# Decrypt a Salesforce Marketing email value encrypted with AmpScript AES in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, salesforce, ampscript

I need to be able to decrypt a string encrypted with AES using AmpScript in C#.  The Salesforce documentation on this seems to be nonexistent, and code I've created doesn't generate values that match what is generated from the encryption tester here: https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/dqooeqrpuoh 
Those values do match what comes out of Salesforce Marketing.

Anyone had any success or can help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: See here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/157898/5202

Comment: Ah yeah, was able to get DES working, but I need AES.

Comment: Trailblazer time!  I'm not sure it can be done without some inside info and considerable effort.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs that's what I thought, hence asking on here.  If they gave information on hashing iterations and how the IV is used, it'd be doable, but unless Salesforce offers that information, it's likely impossible.